# Error while using PhpStorm's git terminal in one repo

Tags: git, phpstorm

I'm having a problem with my Git in PhpStorm in one repo that I can't use the PhpStorm terminal to interact with the local or  BitBucket remote.

The only way I'm able to use git is directly on the virtual machine in /var/www/myproject/ – here I can execute every git command and push the commits
to the remote with no issues unless I have to enter the password every time, and it is very slow compared with the PhpStorm terminal.

I have another project, using also BitBucket, and I can interact via the PhpStorm terminal using the access keys stored in my Mac.

The error I get is:

```
failed MSpanList_Insert 0x62e000 0x5c49179ed896b 0x0
fatal error: MSpanList_Insert
error: external filter git lfs clean %f failed
```

My question is if there is a way to reset the PhpStorm git without losing everything, or another way to solve the problem and keep the remote refs and all the git history because as I mentioned, the other project works fine in the PhpStorm git.

One more thing, each project has different users, but both have the same permissions for any of the remotes.

Thanks in advance for any help on this issue.

Comment: What kind of LFS installation do you have?
Which git version are you using?
Can you try to update to latest version and also update git lfs. 
Please see: https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/issues/1559

Comment: I've done the update and the errors continue but only on this project. Opening the other, there are no errors.

Answer (score 0):

After a couple of days of trying to solve the issue, following numerous tips from StackOverflow and the web, the problem persisted.

I ended up solving the issue, by removing the project and cloning the git repo again on PhpStorm. Did the `git clone my repo url`, `git init`, git `add .`, `git commit` and attempted to create a test branch to push to the remote. **It worked!**

Seems like the problem wahs within the `.git/` files.

Now I'm able again to work with git on PhpStorm without any issues.

Thanks to all who have seen and tried to help, and I hope this may help anyone in the future running on the same problem.